# AI for MMORTS game

Tags: artificial-intelligence, mmo

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but here goes.

I have been a programmer for about 12 years now with experience in php, java, c#, vb.net and asp.  I have always been rather intrigued about Artificial Intelligence. I think it is really the ultimate challenge for any developer.

I have written many simple scripts to play games but nothing compared to what I want to do next. I want to write an AI program that will play a MMORTSG (Massively Multiplayer Online Real Time Strategy Game.  I have been searching through many AI techniques but none seem to tackle the problems that I know I will face:

Problems I can foresee:

1. The game has no "win situation", instead, the best strategy is the one that has the greatest growth in comparison to that of other players. Growth is determined by 3 factors, economy, military and research.
2. Parts of the game state are unpredictable.  Other players can attack me at random.
3. The game is time based and actions take time.  ie.  Building a new building make take several hours.  While that building is being built, no other buildings can be built.

All the AI systems I have researched, require some sort of "Winning Function" to test if the AI has found an end.  Where in my situation it would more likely be something like "I have X, Y, Z options, the best one is X".

ps. Sample code would be awesome.  Even Psuedo would be great.

Comment: Look at POMDPs and MCTS.

Comment: @ziggystar wow, fantastic. POMDPs looks like it deals with a lot more uncertainty that I need to.  On the other hand MCTS looks very promising, I think it will be a great starting point.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a few applications of Artificial Intelligence in the Gaming area, but most of this was for FPS, MMORPGs and RTS games.  The genre type that you appear to be relating to sounds similar to 'Clash of Clans', where research, military and economy as well as random attacks occur over a random period of time, and runs over an endless period of time.

It seems that a model would be used at key points in the game (building is finished, or research is available, or castle is full) to make strategic decisions for progression.  Perhaps a Genetic Algorithm could be applied at key moments determine a suitable sequence of future steps.  A modular neural network could be defined to decide the logical Growth factor to take, but training such a network may be difficult as the game rules can change over time (either from previously unknown resources, research options, military and even game updates).  Scripts are quite common as well in the MMORPG genre, but defining the manual rules could also be difficult without knowing all of the available options.  The fact is that there are so many ways that your challenge can be addressed that it would be difficult to give a clear-cut answer to your problem, let alone the code or psudocode.

Looking briefly over the problem, it appears that the contributing factors to the problem would be current economic state, current military state, current research state, time lost if saving for next upgrade, time required to build next upgrade, cost of upgrade as well as other unknown factors.

Given that the problem has no clear winning objectives, I guess it is a matter of maintaining a healthy balance between the three growth factors.  But how does one define the balance?  Is research more important?  Should you always have money, or just save enough for the next planned upgrade?  Should military be as large as possible?

The challenge that you are placing before yourself is quite adventurous, but I would recommend taking on smaller challenges if you are not yet familiar with the models that AI have to provide.  There are quite a number of Gaming Applications for AI resources available to inspire your model (including ziggystar's examples noted above).

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Yes, the game is very similar to Clash of Clans, the one I have chosen to try is a game I played many years ago called "OGame".  But there are many like it and I would guess that all games of this nature would have a very similar underlying AI Technique.  It is this technique that I am interested in.  The mention of Neural networks and Genetic algorithms has me sitting on the edge of my chair.

Comment: These models are only scratching the surface of what could be accomplished using Artificial Intelligence, but there are a wide variety of approaches available.  If these have you at the edge of your seat, then perhaps it is a good idea to understand the mechanics of these models in order to understand how they work for you.  Please note also that it is commonly frowned upon to generate bots for MMOs in live environments (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_bot)), so please ensure you are following protocol with your agreements before proceeding.

Comment: The end result is actually to create my own game similar but introduce NPC characters in the game.  So instead of a PvP MMO, I want to look into PvE MMO game where the NPC's adhere to the same rules as the players. I read up a bunch about Neural Networks last night and their ability to learn and how that happens from this post: [neural-networks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16419/AI-Neural-Network-for-beginners-Part-of) very interesting!

Comment: The project is starting to look quite broad in scope, but I have had experience in MMO Design and it is no small task.  I spent a year building a base document that only scratches the surface of what an MMO could do.  There are some really good books in this area such as [this](http://www.amazon.com/Designing-Virtual-Worlds-Richard-Bartle/dp/0131018167), but given the current scope it may be a good idea to put your ideas to paper and build a framework of what you would like to achieve.  Good Luck!